# Sorting 2 or more related list boxes in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I'm creating a small visual basic windows form program and I'm trying to implement a sort function for the data. I have easily been able to sort the name list box alphabetically however all the other values associated with that name (address, date etc.) I cannot get to sort with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I'm using to sort the list box:

```
    Private Sub btnsort_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsort.Click
    Dim Templist As New List(Of String)
    For Each LI In lstName.Items
        Templist.Add(String.Concat(LI.ToString))
    Next
    Templist.Sort()
    lstName.DataSource = Templist
End Sub
```

here is the new code:

```
    Private Sub btnsort_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsort.Click
    Dim items = _
Enumerable _
    .Range(0, lstapartment.Items.Count) _
    .Select(Function(n) New With _
    { _
        .apartment = CInt(lstapartment.Items(n)), _
        .name = CStr(lstname.Items(n)), _
        .date = CStr(lsttime.Items(n)), _
        .contact = CInt(lstcontact.Items(n)) _
    }) _
    .OrderBy(Function(x) x.apartment) _
    .ToArray()

    lstname.DataSource = items.Select(Function(x) x.apartment).ToArray()
    lstcontact.DataSource = items.Select(Function(x) x.name).ToArray()
    lstapartment.DataSource = items.Select(Function(x) x.contact).ToArray()
    lsttime.DataSource = items.Select(Function(x) x.Date).ToArray()
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please post the code you currently have that is associated with your question? That'll give you the greatest chance of getting a good quality answer. Right now we're kind of left guessing what "an" answer would be and we're not likely to get "the" answer you need.

Comment: And the other values - are they also in list boxes? And how do you want them to sort?

Comment: This sorts the list box called lstname. I have 3 other list boxes with various things relating to that name(address phone number etc.). When I sort the list box lstname alphabetically using that code I need all the other values regarding that name in the other listboxes to sort corresponding to the order of the items in the name list box. No matter what I try nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving this a go:

```
Private Sub btnsort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsort.Click

    Dim items = _
        Enumerable _
            .Range(0, lstName.Items.Count) _
            .Select(Function(n) New With _
            { _
                .Name = CStr(lstName.Items(n)), _
                .Address = CStr(lstAddress.Items(n)), _
                .Phone = CStr(lstPhone.Items(n)), _
                .Date = CDate(lstDate.Items(n)) _
            }) _
            .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name) _
            .ToArray()

    lstName.DataSource = items.Select(Function(x) x.Name).ToArray()
    lstAddress.DataSource = items.Select(Function(x) x.Address).ToArray()
    lstPhone.DataSource = items.Select(Function(x) x.Phone).ToArray()
    lstDate.DataSource = items.Select(Function(x) x.Date).ToArray()

End Sub
```

This assumes that there are the same number of items in each list box, but that sounds like what is happening.

Comment: this works perfectly, but I'm not sure how to modify it for other purposes. What would I change if I wanted to sort by number rather than alphabetically?

Comment: I had a look at the functions being used and I'm guessing I need to edit the key I'm sorting by (x) in this case but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @HamishMcDonald - The answer I wrote shows how to sort on `String` and `DateTime` - see the `CStr(...)` and `CDate(...)` calls? You could using `CInt(...)` instead if it were a numeric field. The `.OrderBy(...)` call works with any type.

Comment: I can only assumed I messed up somewhere, I have added the the code you posted and I edited to the main post.

Comment: never mind I found out what I was messing up. All is fixed. Thanks a lot for your help.

Just had the wrong type of variables going to the wrong places.